# Extending Spring data's @Document annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to wrap `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document` into a custom annotation , MyDocument.
@MyDocument will inherit everything that the parent @Document has, and the spring data library should also process MyDocument annotation that way it would do it for parent @Document.

Is this possible at all?

I tried below code, but I can't set the required 'indexName' param for @Document.

```
@Document() // HOW TO PUT indexName of @Mydocument into this?
@Persistent
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface MyDocument {
     @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "indexName")
    String indexName();

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "useServerConfiguration")
    boolean useServerConfiguration() default false;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "shards")
    short shards() default 1;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "replicas")
    short replicas() default 1;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "refreshInterval")
    String refreshInterval() default "1s";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "indexStoreType")
    String indexStoreType() default "fs";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "createIndex")
    boolean createIndex() default true;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "versionType")
    VersionType versionType() default VersionType.EXTERNAL;

    // My document specific props
    String myCustomProp() default "myDefault";

    // more properties....


}
```

**REFERENCE** for @Document Annotation by spring data elasticsearch

```
@Persistent
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface Document {

    String indexName();
    @Deprecated
    String type() default "";
    boolean useServerConfiguration() default false;
    
    short shards() default 1;

    short replicas() default 1;

    String refreshInterval() default "1s";

    String indexStoreType() default "fs";

    boolean createIndex() default true;

    VersionType versionType() default VersionType.EXTERNAL;
}
```

**EDITED** : I actually needed to pass all the @Document params via this @MyDocument

**EDIT#2** : Added @Document annotation class for reference

Comment: You're looking for a feature called _meta-annotation_, and I don't know if it's supported for `@Document`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the `value` argument of the `@AliasFor` annotation:

```java
@Document() // HOW TO PUT indexName of @Mydocument into this?
@Persistent
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface MyDocument {

    @AliasFor(value = "indexName", annotation = Document.class)
    String indexName();

    boolean useServerConfiguration() default false;

    short shards() default 1;

    short replicas() default 1;

    String refreshInterval() default "1s";

    String indexStoreType() default "fs";

    boolean createIndex() default true;

    VersionType versionType() default VersionType.EXTERNAL;

    // My document specific props
    String myCustomProp() default "myDefault";

    // more properties....


}
```

**Note** that this only works in spring-data-elasticsearch version 4.2.x (and above).

Comment: @ Document requires indexName value as it is not defaulted. So when I put the 
@ Document annotation on top of MyDocument, I need to pass the index name value, otherwise it doesn't compile.
I want to use MyDocument such that

@ MyDocument(indexName = "my_index", shards = 3, replicas = 2)
public class MySearchableObject{ 
    // fields and getters...
}

Comment: Basically, how do I put the value of MyDocument's indexName and other parameters into Document's parameters with similar name?

Comment: check for example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/4.2.x/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/ComposableAnnotationsUnitTest.java

Comment: I am trying to run a similar test case. For me it just takes the name of class annotated with MyDocument as index name , which would fail if class name has upper case characters.
I am using version 4.0.6 for spring data elastic search (spring boot version 2.3.7). Is this the issue with the version?

Comment: Update : it works with version 4.2.x and not below that. 
@P.J..Meisch
Thanks!

Comment: about uppercase: Elastcisearch itself does not allow uppercase names for indices